# Insert into postgres table using apache drill

Tags: apache-drill

Is it possible to insert data into an existing table in postgres database using apache drill.something similar to

insert into Post_db.test_schema.customer_account_holder_test select customer_id,source_system_id,salutation,first_name,middle_name,last_name,legal_name,gender,identity_proof_name,identity_proof_value from hive.schema_name.customer_account_holder limit 10

Answer (score 2):

In apache drill, Insert is not supported. 
You can creates a new table and populates the new table with rows returned from a SELECT query. Use the CREATE TABLE AS (CTAS) statement in place of INSERT INTO.   CREATE TABLE name AS query;